# How to set up a simple SharePoint List Item to Microsoft Word export option or process without a custom code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

Is there a way to get the contents on a SharePoint List Item into a Microsoft Word Document?

It could be as simple as Viewing the Item -> Copy and Paste into Word Document, but doing this copies the the values from within a "Text Box".

[image]

Expecting more of below:
[image]

I explored the following link, but we likely don't have SharePoint administrator to pull of the workflow.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brenclarke/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use SharePoint designer to create a workflow or use custom code, this requirement is difficult to complete....

I suggest you can use the OOTB function, export to excel, and then convert the excel file into a word file.

Or, if you can, you can also use some code appropriately, using SharePoint 2013 server object model.

More information:

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-word-document/